# Unable to retrieve azure devops project id by terraform

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

Terraform code below:

```
data "azuredevops_project" "project" {
  name = "Test%20Project"
}
resource "azuredevops_variable_group" "main" {
  count      = "${var.azdevops_project != ""?1:0}"
  name       = "${var.application_name}-${var.environment}"
 # project   = "${var.azdevops_project}"
  project_id   = data.azuredevops_project.project.id
  allow_access = true

  variable {
    name  = "database_name"
    value = "${local.db_name}"
  }
  variable {
    name  = "database_login"
    value = "${var.database_administrator_login}"
  }
  variable {
    name  = "Database_fully_qualified_domain_name"
    value = "${azurerm_sql_server.primary.fully_qualified_domain_name}"
  }

  variable {
    name   = "database_password"
    value  = "${random_string.sql_password.result}"
    is_secret = true
  }
}
```

My terraform version is as below:

```
provider "azdevops" {
  account = "testaccount"
  token   = "${data.azurerm_key_vault_secret.azdevops_token.value}"
}

terraform {
  required_providers {
    azuredevops = {
      source = "microsoft/azuredevops"
      version = ">=0.1.0"
      org_service_url = "https://dev.azure.com/testcompany/"
      personal_access_token = "${data.azurerm_key_vault_secret.azdevops_token.value}"
    }
  }
 terraform_0.11.14 --version
Terraform v0.11.14
+ provider.azdevops v1.0.8
+ provider.azurerm v1.44.0
+ provider.null v2.1.2
+ provider.random v2.3.1

Your version of Terraform is out of date! The latest version
is 1.0.1. You can update by downloading from www.terraform.io/downloads.html
```

I am getting error like the below:

```
Unknown token: 952:18 IDENT data.azuredevops_project.project.id
```

Any help shall be most appreciated.

Comment: How did it go? The issue still persists?

Comment: can never happen the answer provided by you never works:) Works like a charm. I realized my mistake. I mixed version 0.11 and 0.12 syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TF 0.11 is **very old**. In such an old version you need to refer to your data source using:

```
 project_id   = "${data.azuredevops_project.project.id}"
```